# Why is Chrome Emulation not scaling but the iPhone Chrome does?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, viewport, emulation

I am trying to emulate a site in Chrome browser's Develeoper Tool's Emulate. (Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143). But the result is not the same as in my mobile phone (also Chrome browser there). But it's the same setup in desktop's Chrome emulation. Device iPhone 4. I have tried both with and without my meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=<?=($_SESSION['resp'] != 'no' ? 'device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' : '1021')?>" />
```

and it's this output that doesn't work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1021" />
```

But as I said, I have tried even without the viewport at all. I have also tried with and without "Emulate viewport" checked.

Here is Desktop printscreen:

[image: Desktop printscreen]

And here is Mobile printscreen:

[image: Mobile printscreen]

Comment: You should give a try to the current Chrome Canary (38). The device emulation has been improved a lot recently.

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov That did it! Thanks! Should I create a new answer to this post now or what?

Comment: Yeah, a new answer will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comment response solved the problem:

> You should give a try to the current Chrome Canary (38). The device emulation has been improved a lot recently. –  Alexander Pavlov

Thank you

Comment: It solved my exact same problem too, i had chrome 36 on desktop and after updating to 38 it emulated as in my phone.